# go-vim not work well after install go with official archive on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, go, vim

Installed go using offciall archive:

https://golang.org/doc/install?download=go1.10.1.linux-amd64.tar.gz

Extract it:

```
$ tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.10.1.linux-amd64.tar.gz
```

Check go version:

```
$ go version
go version go1.10 linux/amd64
```

Use [vim-go](https://github.com/fatih/vim-go) as a vim plugin, when use vim open a go file, it saids:

> vim-go: could not find 'gotags'. Run :GoInstallBinaries to fix it

Therefore, when ran `:GoInstallBinaries`, got messages:

> vim-go: golint not found. Installing github.com/lint/golint to folder
>   ...
>       compile: version "go1.10.1" does not match go tool version "go1.10"

Why it caused version conflict? How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

After rewrote environment variables, it works.

```
export GOROOT=/usr/local/go
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin:$GOPATH/bin

$ go version
go version go1.10.1 linux/amd64

$ vim
:GoInstallBinaries
```